# Google API block request

Tags: linux-networking, google

We are using Google Adwords API to query out data. 
But the problem is that :

[image]

After about 5 successfully requests , Google does not ACK to our SYN request as the image above.

Has anyone faced  this problem?

Comment: How fast are you sending the requests?

Comment: Hi,  I just made about 1 request per second manually by curl command like the image . After about 5 successful requests , Google stop ACK to our connections for about 2-3 minutes .

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a developer account and provide the API key.  https://developers.google.com/

Comment: Hi, I think this is the problem with Google network , not the Google API . Thank you

Comment: The API key will guarantee you a better level of service and connectivity. Without the key your service requests get rejected. this is by design. Google does the same thing with map requests.